# Addon for reports and charts

Tags: plugin, reports

I'm looking for an addon that will enable me to track data from custom fields and output graph or chart type reports. I found NSM Reports but I was wondering if anyone knew of any other possibilities.

thanks
jules

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you just let EE spit out the data and not draw the charts.

For instance you could create an EE template that produces dynamic JSON feed from your EE entries and then hands that data over to another script that parses the data and draws the chart.

I've had good success using [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/) for this but there are many others to choose from, see related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119969/javascript-chart-library